# Can I not use VBA worksheet variable Me to populate a ComboBox embedded in that Excel Worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm simply trying to populate a Combo-box embedded in an Excel worksheet. I'm using Excel 2010 for Mac.

The following returns runtime error 445 "Object doesn't support this action"

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Activate()
With Me.Shapes("TheComboBox").ControlFormat
   .RemoveAllItems
   .List = Array("me", "you")
End With
```

But the following will work fine

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Activate()
With Worksheets(1).Shapes("TheComboBox").ControlFormat
   .RemoveAllItems
   .List = Array("me", "you")
End With
```

Note that the code is in Worksheet 1's Worksheet_Activate sub so Me and Worksheets(1) should refer to the exact same thing (right?).

I found [this](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/705366-excel-2011-mac-visual-basic-applications-form-control-combo-box-return-selected-value.html) similar post online suggesting Excel for Mac doesn't like using ControlFormat on a sheet that is passed as a variable. Is there a workaround that avoids having to hardcode the number or name of the worksheet? I wouldn't want a user to move around or rename the sheet and thereby break it.

Comment: Possibly related: Why is your [Worksheet_Activate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198220.aspx) event macro **Public** and not **Private**? Is this an [osx] peculiarity I'm unaware of?

Comment: Nah I just wanted to be able call it from another procedure as well. Red-herring... Changing it to private doesn't affect the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the [Worksheet_Activate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198220.aspx) event by strict definition makes the worksheet active then I would suppose that the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) should refer unerringly to the correct worksheet.

I would stay away from both the Worksheet [.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196974.aspx) and the [Worksheet.Index property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836415.aspx) as worksheets are commonly moved in the queue and renamed. However, the Worksheet [.CodeName property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837552.aspx) typically remains static although it can be changed with a little effort.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    With Sheet1.Shapes("TheComboBox").ControlFormat
       .RemoveAllItems
       .List = Array("me", "you")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks it does work. Any idea why the Me object is not supported but ActiveSheet is?

Comment: I cannot say. I was testing in a Windows environment and `Me` produced the same results as any other specific worksheet reference. I can only suppose that it has to do with the [osx] environment.

Comment: Ta for checking on Windows.